# How can I write a strikethrough text to a printer that uses CP437 enconding?

Tags: python, printing, codepages, epson, codepage-437

I want to print a strikethrough text to a printer that uses a Code Page 437. We support this functionality in TF-8 printers adding b"\x1b\x4c" between every character. b"\x1b\x4c" represents "~".

I tried using b"\x1b\x4c" but it doesn't work. I also tried to use the backspace command b"\x08" but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Try using b"\xST". It stands for Strike

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).